# Node.js API with Nginx: Block API access to the public

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm using Nginx with Nodejs backend. I use Nodejs for authenticating users and api calls. Currently I have the following in my Nginx configuration:

```
 location /api {

                 proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
```

However, this allows anyone to access `/api` directly. Is there a way to configure this so that users can't directly access `/api`?

**Update**
I tried adding:
`allow 127.0.0.1; deny all;` to the nginx config, however, this also blocks nginx from getting the resources. In other words, users can no longer login or get the resources from api.

I added a middle-ware to express and it always receives `127.0.0.1` (localhost) as the `req.ip` so I cannot do anything on nodejs side to prevent this because all requests are redirected from nginx.

Comment: You can block the outside traffic using firewall. Did you think about that ? However, Nginx also has options to either specify list of IP addresses or an IP range to be allowed or denied. Check out these links - [https://support.hypernode.com/en/hypernode/nginx/how-to-block-allow-ip-addresses-in-nginx] .

Comment: @rootkonda That link doesn't work for me. I have blocked port 5000, however, Nginx still redirects /api to Nodejs and allows users to access the resources directly.

Comment: Here is the link - https://support.hypernode.com/en/hypernode/nginx/how-to-block-allow-ip-addresses-in-nginx

Comment: IP-based protection does not seem to be possible. For nginx, api requests always seem to come from the remote client ip, which can be confirmed by looking at the nginx logs. For the node app, on the other hand, all requests seem to come from localhost, so ip-based limitation is not possible there either. I ended up securing my backend with nginx basic authentication. Then I pass username and password with each fetch (or axios) call in an `Authorization: Basic`... header. However this does not protect against local users, because they can query the backend with a http://localhost address